# Iterating over the entire table, and passing all values that satisfies an inner query to an outer query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
--Pass each of the pmi value from the below query to an outer query.
select pmi 
from support
where supportid = (select supportid 
                   from support 
                   where pmi = '123'
                   order by datereceived DESC
                   fetch first 1 row only)
  and reason ='XYZ'
```

I have multiple rows for a particular `pmi` in my table `support`.
For each set of `pmi`, I need to find the latest row using the `datereceived` column, and then check whether that latest row has a reason 'XYZ'.

Only if the reason is 'XYZ' in the latest row, I have to pass the `pmi` value to an outer query.

It works if I hard code a `pmi` into the inner query, but I want the inner query to iterate over all the `pmi` in the table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a subquery at all. Simply aggregate by pmi and use `KEEP LAST` to check whether the last rows' reason is XYZ:

```
select pmi
from support
group by pmi
having max(reason) keep (dense_rank last order by datereceived) = 'XYZ';
```

`KEEP LAST` is Oracle propriatery, though. If you want something closer to your own query (and standard compliant at that), you can use:

```
select pmi 
from support
where (pmi, datereceived) in
(
  select pmi, max(datereceived)
  from support 
  group by pmi
)
and reason = 'XYZ';
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what analytical functions are useful for:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT pmi, 
             supportid, 
             datereceived, 
             reason, 
             MAX(datereceived) OVER (PARTITION BY pmi) AS MAX_DATE
      FROM support) s
WHERE s.datereceived = s.max_date
AND s.reason = 'XYZ';
```

Comment: Thanks for that Del.

Answer (score 1):

Throsten has a fine answer.  An alternative method that uses standard SQL and aggregation is:

```
select pmi
from support
group by pmi
having max(datereceived) = max(case when reason = 'XYZ' then datereceived end);
```

That is, return all `pmi` where the date on `'XYZ'` is the last date.

Comment: Thanks for that Gordon.